# Spatio-temporal joins in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, buffer, attribute-joins, date

Does anyone know how to count points within radius of another point when a time/temporal condition is met in QGIS?

I assume I need to create buffer zones, but I do not know how to then count occurrences within each buffer zone based on TIME or DATE and then export this to a csv file.

A more detailed explanation of the problem: I need to create a radius buffer zone around a fixed point (A house sale at a specific location on a specific date) and then count the number of interactions within that radius with a separate dataset (Airbnb reviews specified by date and location) - I'm looking to count the number of active Airbnb listings within a given radius of each house sale in the 12 months leading up to the sale date. I need to do this for 1,000s of sales.

I'm not sure where to start. Can QGIS solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there's more than one way to approach this with QGIS. One way would be to use the [processing graphic modeler](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/processing_graphical_modeler.html). You can use this tool to 
map out a process, and then run the process as many times as needed with different inputs.

Here is a rough outline of a process you could use, along with a suggested tool for each step.

Setup: Create the csv file that will store your output.

1. Create a buffer around a house sale point.

   > QGIS geoalgorithms > Vector geometry tools > Fixed distance buffer > temporary output
2. Filter the AirBNB review point layer by date range.

   > SAGA > Vector points tools > Points filter
3. Count the points of the filtered AirBNB layer that fall within the buffer created in step 1.

   > QGIS geoalgorithms > Vector analysis tools > Count points in polygon
4. Add a feature to the csv file. Use the Field Calculator to edit the new feature's attributes to include the count from step 4, along with any other necessary attributes.

   > QGIS geoalgorithms > Vector table tools > Field calculator