# Performing spatio-temporal join/filter between two polygon layers using QGIS

Tags: qgis, filter, spatio-temporal-data

I have been looking for a long time for a good explanation of a spatio-temporal filter or join in QGIS. In my specific case I have two shapefiles (polygons) - one describes the `ignitions` and the other represents `fire perimeter`. Both layers also include an attribute called `year` in which the two  occurred.

My goal is to filter out the `fire` polygons that do not match the `ignition` both spatially but also temporally.

[image]

I have tried [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/255453) by converting my `ignitions` to points, but that did not solve the issue.

How can I easily perform a spatial and temporal filter/join of the two polygon layers in QGIS?

My plan is to look at how the timing of ignitions may change over a time period, therefore, I want to look at how the timing of ignitions is for each year.
I can also look at the average size of the fires that the ignitions have started for each year.

Comment: Since each ignition has a corresponding fire, any usual filter will output the whole layer - so I guess you plan to specify the date the fire started? How?

Comment: No, each ignition does not necessarily have a corresponding fire. There can be a lack of reporting from firefighters, managers etc. I am not interested in the specific date. Fires in a given area happen one time, and it does not return the years after as the vegetation is gone. So on an annual basis is what I need.

Comment: Please define what you mean by "an annual basis is what I need". Maybe describe what you plan on doing with your filtered layer, so it becomes more clear how the filter should behave.

Comment: I have tried to update the post with my plan now. Thanks.

I basically mean that I would like to be able to compare how the ignitions change for each year and how that effects the fire size for each year.

Comment: That would simply be a filter of `year = 20xx` on the fire layer?

Comment: For how many years are you trying to do this? and in what format is the year written? Knowing this might help in how much it should be automated.  

Simplest would be to create filtered layers of both your fires  and ignitions layer and use batch processing in the clipping tool. However, for a large number of years I wouldn't go that route.

Comment: I am concerned about the years 2001 to 2018. How would you filter this simply based on the years? The years are just written as intergers.

Comment: If you copy the layer in your case 18 times, and then write as @erik suggests,  year = 20XX (by right clicking on the layer you want to filter and choose filter). Then, if you go to the processing toolbox, right-click the clipping tool and choose  "batch processing". You can then input all these layers and corresponding clipping masks at once. Meaning that you only have to perform clippiing 1 time for all output.

Comment: This seems like a silly work around for doing this. There is simply no smarter way in QGIS?

Comment: I guess you could do this using SQL and a virtual layer. First check for matching years, then check for `ST_DISJOINT` features where the years match. Could be done in one request, but my SQL is too rusty.

Comment: you can adapt the solution I gave you a few years ago, by changing the date comparison for a simpler year equality between the layers https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/345287/choosing-one-certain-point-out-of-many-for-nearby-polygon-based-on-coordinates/345297#345297

Comment: @JGH, I am working on that one too. With the layers containing `1000` ignitions and `3000` fire perimeters, how long should I expect it to run?
For me, the computer cannot really process this within the virtual layer you suggest.

Comment: It depends on the polygon complexity and the presence of a spatial index. Virtual Layers can be fussy at times. The same query using a DB like Postgres+PostGIS would take no time

Comment: Thanks JGH, I think it worked this time compared to two years ago. Thank you a lot!